# Rails/Heroku: Cannot find source of ExecJS SyntaxError Unexpected token: eof (undefined)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, asset-pipeline, uglifyjs

I'm trying to get my assets pipeline set up according to the [Heroku guide for Rails 4](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline), but when I enter this at the console:

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

I get this error:

```
rake aborted!
ExecJS::ProgramError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: eof (undefined) (line: 46, col: 0, pos: 1394)

Error
    at new JS_Parse_Error (<eval>:3623:11948)
    at js_error (<eval>:3623:12167)
    at croak (<eval>:3623:22038)
    at token_error (<eval>:3623:22175)
    at unexpected (<eval>:3623:22263)
    at block_ (<eval>:3623:28063)
    at ctor.body (<eval>:3623:27686)
    at function_ (<eval>:3623:27782)
    at expr_atom (<eval>:3623:31068)
    at maybe_unary (<eval>:3624:1752)
new JS_Parse_Error ((execjs):3623:11948)
js_error ((execjs):3623:12167)
croak ((execjs):3623:22038)
token_error ((execjs):3623:22175)
unexpected ((execjs):3623:22263)
block_ ((execjs):3623:28063)
ctor.body ((execjs):3623:27686)
function_ ((execjs):3623:27782)
expr_atom ((execjs):3623:31068)
maybe_unary ((execjs):3624:1752)
V8::Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: eof (undefined)
at js_error (<eval>:3623:12167)
at croak (<eval>:3623:22038)
at token_error (<eval>:3623:22175)
at unexpected (<eval>:3623:22263)
at block_ (<eval>:3623:28063)
at ctor.body (<eval>:3623:27686)
at function_ (<eval>:3623:27782)
at expr_atom (<eval>:3623:31068)
at maybe_unary (<eval>:3624:1752)
at expr_ops (<eval>:3624:2523)
at maybe_conditional (<eval>:3624:2615)
at maybe_assign (<eval>:3624:3058)
at expression (<eval>:3624:3384)
at expr_list (<eval>:3623:31548)
at subscripts (<eval>:3624:1461)
at expr_atom (<eval>:3623:31132)
at maybe_unary (<eval>:3624:1752)
at expr_ops (<eval>:3624:2523)
at maybe_conditional (<eval>:3624:2615)
at maybe_assign (<eval>:3624:3058)
at expression (<eval>:3624:3384)
at expr_atom (<eval>:3623:30820)
at maybe_unary (<eval>:3624:1752)
at expr_ops (<eval>:3624:2523)
at maybe_conditional (<eval>:3624:2615)
at maybe_assign (<eval>:3624:3058)
at expression (<eval>:3624:3384)
at simple_statement (<eval>:3623:25942)
at <eval>:3623:23902
at <eval>:3623:22954
at <eval>:3624:3759
at parse (<eval>:3624:3999)
at parse (<eval>:3958:22)
at uglifier (<eval>:4003:13)
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

I have seen other posts on SO with similar errors like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36980123/uglify-js-error-unexpected-token-eof-undefined?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634049/uglify-js-error-unexpected-token-eof-undefined?noredirect=1&lq=1), but in both of those cases, the error was nice enough to say which file the error was in.  In my error, I don't see a reference to the actual file, so I'm stumped on where to go from here.

Looking back, when I started trying to fix this, it DID show a file (or something), but I can't make heads or tails of it (nor do I know why it stopped showing the location of the error...):

```
Error
    at new JS_Parse_Error (/private/var/folders/hz/1d1f64ln59b4_pl632lm6mpr0000gn/T/execjs20170121-47471-7jr3eejs:3623:11948)
    at js_error (/private/var/folders/hz/1d1f64ln59b4_pl632lm6mpr0000gn/T/execjs20170121-47471-7jr3eejs:3623:12167)
    at croak (/private/var/folders/hz/1d1f64ln59b4_pl632lm6mpr0000gn/T/execjs20170121-47471-7jr3eejs:3623:22038)
    at token_error (/private/var/folders/hz/1d1f64ln59b4_pl632lm6mpr0000gn/T/execjs20170121-47471-7jr3eejs:3623:22175)
    at unexpected (/private/var/folders/hz/1d1f64ln59b4_pl632lm6mpr0000gn/T/execjs20170121-47471-7jr3eejs:3623:22263)
    at block_ (/private/var/folders/hz/1d1f64ln59b4_pl632lm6mpr0000gn/T/execjs20170121-47471-7jr3eejs:3623:28063)
    at /private/var/folders/hz/1d1f64ln59b4_pl632lm6mpr0000gn/T/execjs20170121-47471-7jr3eejs:3623:27686
    at function_ (/private/var/folders/hz/1d1f64ln59b4_pl632lm6mpr0000gn/T/execjs20170121-47471-7jr3eejs:3623:27782)
    at expr_atom (/private/var/folders/hz/1d1f64ln59b4_pl632lm6mpr0000gn/T/execjs20170121-47471-7jr3eejs:3623:31068)
    at maybe_unary (/private/var/folders/hz/1d1f64ln59b4_pl632lm6mpr0000gn/T/execjs20170121-47471-7jr3eejs:3624:1752)
new JS_Parse_Error ((execjs):3623:11948)
js_error ((execjs):3623:12167)
croak ((execjs):3623:22038)
token_error ((execjs):3623:22175)
unexpected ((execjs):3623:22263)
block_ ((execjs):3623:28063)
(execjs):3623:27686
function_ ((execjs):3623:27782)
expr_atom ((execjs):3623:31068)
maybe_unary ((execjs):3624:1752)
```

I looked in the directory mentioned there and see no relevant files.  I searched my whole system for "execjs20170121-47471-7jr3ee" and "execjs20170121-47471-7jr3eejs" with no luck.

From what I've read in the other posts, it looks like Uglifier is erroring out while parsing my Javascript, but again, I just don't know where to look to try to fix it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem.
You should see the error in your production logs since you ran the command with "RAILS_ENV=production".
 My production logs point to:        `/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb in exec at line 39`

This is the line:

```
 extract_result(@runtime.exec_runtime(filepath), filepath)
```

Though the line means nothing to me, it's evident that it's a "filepath" issue.
It might be possible that some of your fonts are not properly defined.
You should reference your font-urls with `<%= asset_path "..." %>` or sass-rails as explained [here](http://%3C%25=%20font_path('fontawesome-webfont.eot')%20%25%3E)
If it still doesn't work, try changing: `config.assets.compile = false`
to   `config.assets.compile = true` in production.rb as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324063/rails-4-images-not-loading-on-heroku)